# Type of set theory in Halmos' naive set theory.

Tags: set-theory

The title of Paul Halmos' book *Naive Set Theory* suggests that it treats set theory *naively* rather than *axiomatically*. However, the book constructs set theory from well-chosen axioms and in this sense the book develops set theory axiomatically except that it does not define the notion of a set formally. Also, Russell's paradox is eliminated, which is in general part of a set theory developed in the "naive" way.

As there are several types of axiomatic set theories, I am curious which type of set theory is treated in *Naive Set Theory*. I would think it is the Zermelo-Fraenckel set theory with axiom of choice. The book assumes the axiom of choice namely in $\S15$.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: It's "naive" in the sense that it's more of a beginner's text. However, it's certainly rigorous.

Comment: The way mathematicians use the word "naive" means non-axiomatically and less formally. Therefore, it also means less "rigorously."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you have surmised, Halmos develops ordinary ZFC from axioms.

Note that the fact that he "does not define the notion of a set formally" is not an *exception* from doing things axiomatically -- on the contrary, it is the *very core* of the axiomatic method (from a modern perspective) that you *don't* bother to attempt to define what the objects you're speaking about *are*. Instead we have axioms that tell us how those objects *behave*, and that is all we need to know in order to prove things about them.

The title of Halmos's book is something of a misnormer, at least relative to how the terminology has come to be used.  Usually, "naive set theory" means the inconsistent theory assumed by Cantor and the rest of the 19th century, in which every definable collection is a set, leading to Russell's paradox and others. But that is certainly not what Halmos is doing.

What *Halmos* calls "naive" seems to be simply the fact that he develops set theory *without first presenting a theory of formal logic* -- so he has explicit axioms *for set theory*, but the way he reasons *from* those axioms are by the ordinary quasi-formal English prose that is used in the rest of mathematics too, rather than the usual formal-logic game of symbol sequences and exact mechanical rules for "what is a valid proof".

Comment: I did not know there was an inconsistency in Cantor's thinking about sets. I thought the inconsistency arose from Frege's axiom of comprehension, which was rejected by Cantor, or so I thought. But I'm not a historian or a set-theoretician, much less a historian of set theory.

Comment: @bof: Neither am I, so you may be right. As far as what I've read in secondary sources, Cantor didn't use explicit axioms, but I've always understood he assumed that every collection he could describe would be a set. Feel free to edit in a description of the usual "naive set theory" that makes fewer extraneous assumptions if you can come up with one, though.

Comment: One genuinely naive error during the historical beginning of set theory was to assume that for any property $P,$ the set $\{x:P(x)\}$ exists. Which leads to Russell's Paradox. (like the ancient Greek "barber paradox": If the barber shaves all those and only those who don't shave themselves, does the barber shave the barber?). This erroneous assumption also yields a proof, from the other axioms, of the axiom of the existence of an infinite set. E.g $\{x: x$ is an ordinal and $\forall y\leq x \;(\cup y=y\iff y=0)\}.$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Does that book talks about regularity axiom?

Comment: Cantor was well aware of the various paradoxes involved in his theory of sets from a fairly early period.  He was especially aware of the Burali-Forti paradox, after it was published in 1897. He also is quickly apprised of the Russell Paradox as soon as it is discovered.  He is concerned about such matters in his later writing, usually discusses them  under the heading of the problem of "Limitation of Size." There is a very fine book on Cantor's developing ideas about these matters in Michael Hallet's "Cantorian Set Theory and Limitation of Size," a must read for all Set Theory afficianados!!

Answer (score 2):

An interesting point is that Halmos doesn't ever introduce the axiom of regularity, which he alludes to in a cryptic statement (Chapter 2, the "axiom" of specification) about how sets which contain themselves don't seem sensible but might exist--well, they don't if you introduce the axiom of regularity.  Probably because it is not necessary in the vast majority of mathematical work, Halmos chose to omit it completely.  That is probably another reason Halmos used the term "naive."  He didn't even bother to introduce all of ZFC because the text is merely intended to give the working mathematician all of the set theory necessary in normal settings; I think he is merely warning the reader that this book doesn't serve as the basis for an honest-to-goodness course in set theory, as that isn't the stated purpose for the book.  In short, the book develops ZFC minus regularity.

Answer (score 2):

Halmos explains, (1960), in his Preface, page v, that 'In set theory "naive" and "axiomatic" are contrasting words. The present treatment might best be described as axiomatic set theory from the naive point of view.' He further explains how some (not all) axioms are used and stated in proofs in the book. And that the book is (partly) informal, but can be made formal.

Accordingly, if the book was  formal (and rigorous) it would begin with terms that are undefined (or "primitive") and set or cast in axioms (or postulates) as propositions.

It follows that you (the student) are expected to know (intuitively) that a set is (merely) a "collection" of distinct things. And, therefore, the topics he covers will be true in any axiomatic set theory; anyway, all known axiomatic theories are essentially equivalent to the extent that their respective axioms are; but you can always drop an axiom and see what you get.

Finally, if a system is informal (or naive) then it is not rigorous; there is, obvious some ambiguity somewhere.

Halmos also recommends two books: (1) the classic ("One of the most beautiful), "Set Theory," by Felix Hausdorff. Unfortunate, the 1st edition (1914) exists only in German; but the 2nd and 3rd editions have been translated into English; and Hausdorff abridged the first 6 chapters which contained substantial set theory (I assume, also in a naive way). (2) The second book "Axiomatic Set Theory" by Patrick Suppes (1960), which exists as a 1972 Dover Publications, Inc. facsimile reprint.